# Issue from Pyhton3 connecting Sqlite3 in-memory database

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, in-memory-database

I am facing an issue while trying to connect from Python3.4 to a memory database in sqlite3. I am using the following code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('/data/smc/smcdm.db')
c= conn.cursor()
c.execute("ATTACH DATABASE 'file:/dev:/shm/bacnet_values.db?cache=shared' AS bac_v")
db_cursor_system = c.execute("SELECT dm_ver, bacnet_ver, iot_ver, 
smc_db_ver, system_version from system_details")
for row in db_cursor_system:
    print ("dm_ver = ", row[0])
    print ("bacnet_ver = ", row[1])
    print ("iot_ver = ", row[2])
    print ("smc_db_ver =", row[3]);
    print ("system_version =", row[4]);
conn.commit
c.fetchall()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database: file::/dev:/shm/bacnet_values.db?cache=shared
```

Can anyone help, thanks!

Comment: That's an... Interesting path for a database. And URI filenames are only supported if the database connection used the appropriate flag to `sqlite3_open_v2()`.... No idea if the python bindings do.

Comment: Use a filename of `:memory:` for an in-memory database.

Comment: still not working!

Comment: `sqlite3.connect(':memory:')` or an ATTACH using it as the file name doesn't work? That's odd.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to have two *different* processes use one in-memory database? You can't do that. https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html